# python boto3 ec2 describe-instance-status check email

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to find how how to get the following information on all my EC2 instances:

- Name of Instance
- InstanceID
- System status check
- instance status check

If system or instance status check is not ok or fails, then send email.

Any idea?

I only got the following:

```py
import boto3

for status in ec2.meta.client.describe_instance_status()['InstanceStatuses']:
    print(status)
```

but this has too much information.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the individual data elements from the response object:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instance_status()

for instance in response['InstanceStatuses']:
  instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
  system_status = instance['SystemStatus']
  instance_status = instance['InstanceStatus']
```

The `Name` of the instance is not provided in this call. It is stored as a Tag, where `Key='Name'` and the `Value` is the name of the instance. You would need to call `describe_instances()` to obtain tag information.

The easiest way to send an email notification would be to:

- Create an Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) Topic
- Subscribe to the Topic with your email address
- Add code to send a message to the SNS Topic:

```py
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

response = client.publish(
    TopicArn='<your Topic ARN>',
    Message='string',
    Subject='string',
)
```

Comment: how do i check the instance and system check. if failed or not OK, then send an alert

Comment: Here is what I got so far....

Comment: I have added information about sending an email via Amazon SNS.